# Overriding Javascript's delete operator?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to override Javascript's delete operator to some custom function.

I've used `Object.defineProperty(obj, "prop", { get: ..., set: ... })` to override the default getter and setter but I also need to get the delete event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can not override JavaScript's `delete` operator.

Comment: @Sajuuk The spec doesn't have an allowance for it.

Answer (score 1):

you can see an interesting blog on Why not Operator Overloading in JavaScript? [here](http://blog.thejit.org/2009/01/27/why-not-operator-overloading-in-javascript/)